# I've handled various materials

Tags: riddle

> I eat the used
>
> I steal the maid
>
> I concave the face
>
> And I really like to me

Who am I?

Comment: Beautiful riddle..beautifully beautiful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are:

> A **Spoon.**

I eat the used

> A **spoon** is used for eating.

I steal the maid

> A **spoon** can be made of steel.

I concave the face

> A **spoon** has a concave 'face'.

And I really like to me

> I think this is a reference to **spoon**ing? 'I really like to spoon'

Title, I've handeled various materials

> **Spoons** have handles and handle a lot of different materials.

Comment: Nice! about the other lines - notice that there's a single linguistic rule for deciphering all of them

Comment: @Dotan Thank you for the little push, all finished :)